# Smart Battery Case: Can't find notification center in ios11

Tags: notifications, ios

I just got Apple's smart battery case for my iPhone 6S, but I'm having difficulty finding the charge status anywhere. It is supposed to be on the lock screen and the notification center. However, it doesn't show on the lock screen for me at all.

This is iOS 11, so when I swipe down from the top I get the same view as the lock screen. Still no battery charge status, of course. Swiping right takes me to the Today view, which has plenty of widgets but none for charge status.

From googling it seems you are supposed to be able to see yet another notification view by swiping up from the middle of the screen, but doing that doesn't do anything for me. I am on 11.0.3.

EDIT: It turns out that the battery status on the lock screen is only shown *right* when you plug or unplug the USB cable, for about 2 seconds. It doesn't normally show up. Man, I hate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charging status a widget in the the Today View.

> If you already attached your iPhone to your case, look for the charging status in Today View on your iPhone.
>
> [image]

[Charge your iPhone with your Smart Battery Case](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT205443)

If the widget doesn't appear, tap the Edit button shown at the bottom of the screenshot and add it to the widgets you see.

To access Today View,

> swipe right over the Home screen, Lock screen, or while you're looking at your notifications.

[Use widgets on your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207122)

In addition, the charging status is shown on the lock screen briefly when you connect/disconnect the case or power.

> As you attach your iPhone to your case, a charging status appears on the Lock screen. The status also appears when you connect the case to power or disconnect from power.

[Charge your iPhone with your Smart Battery Case](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT205443)